# JAX-RS (Jersey 2) - authorization using JSR 250 annotations

Tags: java, security, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

**Intro**

Jersey: 2.9

This part of [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e10744) describes how to provide authorization for REST services. There are two ways to do that:

- standard Servlet way, using configuration in web.xml
- much better solution using JSR 250 annotations

The First approach works fine, but I cannot make the second work.

**Case 1 (using web.xml):**

This example works. It is for informational purpose. If you want just jump do the second one, which does not work.

Resource is very simple:

```java
@Path("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHelloWorld(){
         return "Hello World!!!";
    }
}
```

Security configuration is placed in web.xml file, which looks like that:

```xml
<web-app ...>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- SECURITY -->

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>boss</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>DefaultRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>

</web-app>
```

This example works fine. When I try to access http://{myhost}:8080/{war_name}/rest/HelloWorld I have to provide username and password. This means that Realm and configuration in database is just fine. So there is no need to show it here.

**Case 2 (JSR 250 annotations):**

This example does not work. The resource is almost the same as in the first example, just some annotations are added:

```java
@Path("/HelloWorld")
@PermitAll
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @RolesAllowed("boss")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHelloWorld(){
        return "Hello World!!!";
    }
}
```

As you see, two annotations are added. It is the same security policy like in the first example, but defined using annotations insted of web.xml.

Now web.xml looks like that:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>DefaultRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>

</web-app>
```

In addition new class is added (like described in documentation):

```java
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        super(HelloWorldResource.class);
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);     
    }
}
```

This class is important. As you see required RolesAllowedDynamicFeature is registered.
So two main steps:
 - adding annotations to resource
 - registering RolesAllowedDynamicFeature 
are done.

**Problem:**

Second example does not work. Popup to provide username and password never shows up. Every time response is 403 Forbidden. This is not a problem with Realm and database configuration since this configuration works fine with the first example.

So the question is: what is wrong with my second implementation?

Tnaks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the ResourceConfig sub-class, try add this to you web.xml  block

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.RolesAllowedResourcFilterFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
```